# How to get type contained by protobuf's RepeatedCompositeContainer or RepeatedScalarContainer in python3?

Tags: python, serialization, protocol-buffers, backend, proto

I'm writing a Python app for serializing and sending `protobuf3` messages. I'd like to make some sort of interactive UI that allows to choose a message and assign it on the fly. I've got a pretty big set of those messages, thus I don't want to make a `get` function for every message, but make one that will work with all of them.

To `get` all message fields, I can simply get all the message's attributes and choose those that are its fields, which is easy. Then, to know what type is the attribute, I use `type(getattr(my_message, current_field))`. And now there is the problem. Suppose those are my messages:

```proto
message myMess1 {
    //some fields
}

message myMess2 {
    string some_string = 1
    repeated myMess1 myMess1Field = 2
}
```

Now, there is no problem with assigning some_string field.

`type(getattr(myMess2Instance, someStringFieldName))` returns `string`, so I know to feed it with string.

But what to do with the repeated myMess1 field? 
`type(getattr(MyMess2Instance, myMess1FieldName))` actually returns `google.protobuf.pyext._message.RepeatedCompositeContainer`, which says nothing about what type is contained in it. How can I get it?

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar Protobuf parsing issue, here is what I do "hope it helps":

Say we have this response message:

```py
>>> msg
path {
}
path {
  value: "Arts & Entertainment"
}
path {
  value: "Comics & Animation"
}
```

Convert it to dictionary:

```py
>>> from google.protobuf.json_format import MessageToDict
>>> d = MessageToDict(msg)
{'path': ['', 'Arts & Entertainment', 'Comics & Animation']}
```

Join the dictionary list of values as a string:

```py
>>> " ".join(d["path"]).strip()
'Arts & Entertainment Comics & Animation'
```

Answer (score 5):

This really perplexed me for a while since no documentation seems to be generated. The key is to see that `RepeatedCompositeContainer` behaves like a list. You can iterate on the contents, which in the example would have the `myMess1` generated type. E.g:

```
for myMess1Element in myMess2Instance.myMess1FieldName:
    print(f"{myMess1Element.some_field=}")
    print(f"{myMess1Element.other_field=}")
```

If you somehow knew the number of repeats of that message ahead of time, you could index a particular one. E.g:

```
print(f"{myMess2Instance.myMess1FieldName[0]}")
```

It would be advisable to check the length though, since the message could be repeated any number of times (including zero).

Answer (score 1):

One way to figure out the type contained by protobuf's `RepeatedCompositeContainer` is by using the `add()` function of `RepeatedCompositeFieldContainer`:

https://googleapis.dev/python/protobuf/latest/google/protobuf/internal/containers.html#google.protobuf.internal.containers.RepeatedCompositeFieldContainer.add

Based on the above documentation,

```
add(**kwargs: Any) → _T
Adds a new element at the end of the list and returns it. Keyword arguments may be used to initialize the element.
```

The key thing is the `return_type` -> notice it returns the type `_T`. This can give us an idea of what the type of elements will be within the `RepeatedCompositeContainer`.

So in your example, you can do something like this:

```
container = getattr(MyMess2Instance, myMess1FieldName)
elem_type = container.add()
```

Now the `elem_type` should be of the form `myMess1`.